# Error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" al intentar usar LaTex en un notebook mediante $$

Tags: python, jupyter, latex, ipython, markdown

Estoy intentando usar LaTeX en Jupyter Notebook, el código es éste:

```latex
$$
\frac{d\mathbf{R}(t)}{dt}=\mathbf{V}(t) \tag{1}
$$
$$
m\frac{d\mathbf{V}(t)}{dt}=-\zeta\mathbf{V}(t)-k\mathbf{R}(t) \tag{2}
$$
```

Pero obtengo la excepción:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

al ejecutar la celda. Ya probé con `#` y `%` pero nada funciona.

Comment: Hola Alejandra, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. sería conveniente que dieras algunos detalles más de cómo y dónde ejecutas lo que muestras, sobretodo porque no es código Python válido y no agregas más etiquetas ¿Jupyter Notebook y Latex quizás?

Comment: Estoy usando Jupyter Network, disculpa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que estás intentando usar Latex directamente en una celda en modo normal (código). Lógicamente eso no es sintaxis Python válida, por lo que obtenemos la susodicha excepción.

Tienes varias opciones:

- Seleccionar esa celda para que sea de tipo markdown:

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  también puedes hacerlo directamente haciendo click fuera de la celda en si, pero a la izquierda de ésta, donde aparece `In [...]:` y pulsando <kbd>m</kbd>.
- Usar el comando mágico `%%latex` antes de la primera línea de código en la celda:

  ```
  %%latex
  $$
  \frac{d\mathbf{R}(t)}{dt}=\mathbf{V}(t) \tag{1}
  $$
  $$
  m\frac{d\mathbf{V}(t)}{dt}=-\zeta\mathbf{V}(t)-k\mathbf{R}(t) \ta
  g{2}
  $$
  ```
- Usar la clase [`IPython.display.Latex`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Latex):

  ```
  from IPython.display import Latex

  Latex(r"""\begin{eqnarray}
  \frac{d\mathbf{R}(t)}{dt}=\mathbf{V}(t) \tag{1}\\
  m\frac{d\mathbf{V}(t)}{dt}=-\zeta\mathbf{V}(t)-k\mathbf{R}(t) \ta
  g{2}
  \end{eqnarray}
  """)
  ```
- Usar la clase [`IPython.display.Math`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Math):

  ```
  from IPython.display import Math

  Math(r"""\frac{d\mathbf{R}(t)}{dt}=\mathbf{V}(t) \tag{1}\\
  m\frac{d\mathbf{V}(t)}{dt}=-\zeta\mathbf{V}(t)-k\mathbf{R}(t) \ta
  g{2}
  """)
  ```